# MongoDb indexes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC application where some of the data is stored in a MongoDb database.

My collection contains documents which are stored like this (C# class example):

```
public class MeteredDataReading
{
    [BsonId]
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public string EDIEL { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartOccurence { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public DateTime Occurence { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Double)]
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when it comes to indexes, I'm a bit lost. The fields we're using the most is: `EDIEL`, `Occurence` and `CreatedDate` An example query (pesudo) would be:

`Get all MeteredDataReadings where EDIEL = 1234 and occurence >= startDate and occurence <= endDate and CreatedDate <= deadlineDate order by occurence descending`

So, the first pondering I have is: how to make the indexes. Should I simply just create a single-field index for all three fields (EDIEL, Occurence and CreatedDate)? Or should I have a look at creating maybe a compound index? And if so, which fields should be included in the compount index? EDIEL and Occurence?

Second thing I'm a bit stuck with is where and when these indexes should be created. Should I create them when the application starts up, in `Application_Start()`? Or should they be created once via the mongodb shell and and that's it?

Any help/hint/insight is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, You need to set compound index. 
    `db.MeteredDataReading.createIndex( { "EDIEL": 1, "occurence": 1,     "CreatedDate":1 } )`

MongoDb Indexes are very important aspect of database design and application performance.

Also you can check whether your queries are doing column reads using explain(). If they are doing column scans you need to index and make sure, queries are hitting the index and disk reads are avoided.

```
`db.MeteredDataReading.find({$query:
   { "EDIEL": 1234, 
     {"occurence" :$gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
                   $lte: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")},
     "CreatedDate":$lte: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")},
     $orderby: { occurence : -1 } }).explain("executionStats")`
```

Comment: Hi Mortensen, did above queries help you.